# How to execute oracle function from function?

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, stored-functions

i has function which return`s cursor for user init like this:

```
     FUNCTION getUserInfo(u_id IN VARCHAR2) return CURSOR;
```

How i can execute this function in another select like this:

```
     FUNCTION getUserList RETURN CURSOR IS
     curs CURSOR;
     BEGIN
     OPEN curs for
     SELECT getUserInfo(u_id) FROM ( SELECT ID u_id from users WHERE USERROLE =   10);
     RETURN curs;
     END;
     END getUserList;
```

After this select i has i column with cursors;
P.s. I`am suppose, what i must to FETCH returned cursors(open) from getUserInfo in LOOP,but no ideas how to do this...

Comment: It is not clear what is your problem. Does your function getUserList compile without errors?

Comment: getUserList compiling without errors, on execute this a had column with cursors, but i need return like :'Name','Age','Dept','Solary' as in getUserInfo;

Comment: That won't compile as it is. When you created it it should have said 'compiled with warnings'. Use `show errors` or query the `user_errors` view to see the actual errors. Your question is not clear though, are you then trying to call this from somewhere else?

Comment: getUserInfo for initialize current user, but getUserList for Admin to see user`s list; where is errors in query?

Comment: Well, you've changed `from` to `for` now, but you still have an extra `end`, and what is `cursor` here - do you really use `sys_refcursor`, maybe?. Guess this isn't quite your real code. How are you calling `getuserlist`, and from which client?

Comment: Alex, yes CURSOR IS A SYS_REFCURSOR and this isn`t real code, i`am call getUserList: select getUserList from dual; And this function reurns sys_refcursor contains many SYS_REFCURSOR rows. But finally this function will be called from java class and fills jtable.

Comment: Do you have only one user with USERROLE equal to 10?

Comment: Guneli, no "USERROLE=10" only for exmaple, this  returns ~10 rows.

Comment: If you're calling it from Java you can execute the function and then use `stmt.getCursor()`, which will give you a `resultSet` you can iterate over? From SQL*Plus/SQL Developer you can use the `variable` and `print` commands to see what's in the cursor. Still not quite sure what the question is and what the answer will look like *8-)

Comment: @GeorgeVassilev, so you want getUserInfo to be executed 10 times and get the result of these 10 cursor in one cursor?

Comment: Alex, problem in - getUserList return curs witch contains many cursors returned from getUserInfo...For illustration,i`am attach in screenshot.

Comment: Guneli, yes i execute getUserInfo for every user.